# Determining how many bytes to write while creating a binary dump of an object

Tags: c++

This post pertains to some [sample code on Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reading-and-writing-binary-file-in-c-cplusplus) that discusses binary IO.

The sample code tries to write an array of size 3 of objects of the following struct to a binary file:

```
struct Student {
   int roll_no;
   string name;
};
```

To make a call to the `write` method on the `ofstream` class, we have to specify the number of bytes to write.  For this the following code snippet is given:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      wf.write((char *) &wstu[i], sizeof(Student));
```

The size of each Student object is different, since the students have different name lengths.  However, `sizeof` will return the compile time size of the each object (which is fixed).

---

**Question:** How does the code snippet correctly figure out how many bytes to write for each object of the array, into the binary file?

Comment: *How does the code snippet correctly figure out how many bytes to write for each object of the array,* -- It doesn't figure out anything, since it is not correct.  This is exactly the reason why learning C++ from shoddy websites instead of good C++ books leads new programmer's astray.

Comment: Also, the code at that site seems to "work", but it is totally wrong.  The reason why it looks like it works is that the `std::string` class has something called "short-string-optimization" (SSO), where strings that are usually less than 20 bytes are stored in a regular array, and not dynamically allocated.  Take the code at that site and try to write a string 50 or 100 bytes in length, instead of 9 or 10 bytes.  You will see garbage written to the file as soon as the string is larger.  That is a garbage website or at the very least, little to no peer-review of articles posted there.

Comment: Now I wonder if that URL link is the reason why so many questions concerning "binary file reading and writing" are asked here.  I was always trying to get to the source of where this erroneous coding was coming from, and maybe I've found it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie FYI, I tried a 350 character long string and it still worked.  I have a hard time understanding why that is so.

Comment: It could never work, for the simple fact that the second parameter to the `write` function denotes the number of bytes.  What is `sizeof(Student)`?  Is it 350?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In my quest to understand the above mentioned code segment I created [another post before this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74410780/computing-the-sizeof-string-object), which cost my reputation 6 points (3 down votes), before it was closed :)

Comment: [Here is a small program](https://godbolt.org/z/zYKjo55G4).  Unless you have a magical program, how will `write` know to write 10000 bytes to the file, when the `sizeof(Student)` is 40?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is incorrect. You cannot just write such a structure to a file because the structure contains `std::string` which contains a pointer.

Instead, you have to serialize the string, i.e. get the `const char*` and write it manually.

You want object serialization, i.e. ability to convert it from/to plain bytes. This is different depending on the object you have to convert.

Generally, you 'd need some more complex mechanism to read/write variable runtime length stuff to a file, such as XML or JSON.

Writing structures directly only works if their content is POD (Plain Old Data), without pointers. Even so, it creates a non-portable save/load mechanism since if you alter the contents of the strucure, files already saved may be broken.

A quick example using my own [XML library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/998388/XMLplusplus-version-3-The-Cplusplus11-Update-of-My):

```
 struct Student {
   int roll_no;
   string name;

   void Save(const char* f)
   {
      XML3::XML x(f);
      auto&root = x.GetRootElement();
      root.vv("roll").SetValueInt(roll_no);
      root.vv("name").SetValue(name.c_str());
      x.Save();
   }


   void Load(const char* f)
   {
      XML3::XML x(f);
      auto&root = x.GetRootElement();
      roll_no = root.vv("roll").GetValueInt(0);
      name = root.vv("name").GetValue();
   }
};
```

As @PaulMcKenzie correctly says, the reason why it looks like it works is that `the std::string` class has something called "short-string-optimization" (SSO), where strings that are usually less than 20 bytes are stored in a regular array, and not dynamically allocated. If you try to write a larger than the SSO capacity string, you will see garbage written to the file.

Comment: You may also want to point out what I mentioned in my comment in the main section of why the code at the site they linked to seems to "work" (short-string-optimization).